# Value does not fall within expected range when applying property to Windows 10 Shortcut

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm attempting to modify the `TargetPath` of a shortcut on Windows using PowerShell, and when I go to apply the new path, I'm receiving a 'Value does not fall within the expected range' error. I'm assuming it has something to do with quotation marks, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$AppPath = '"app.exe"'
$AppFullPath = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\app\app.exe"'
$TargetPath = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c start $AppPath /high $AppFullPath"
$DesktopShortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut('C:\users\user\desktop\app.lnk')
$DesktopShortcut.TargetPath = $TargetPath
```

`$TargetPath` looks good, and I can manually set its output through the GUI and it works as expected, but not in PowerShell.

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c start "app.exe" /high "C:\Program Files (x86)\app\app.exe"`

Comment: Have a look: [Modify shortcut file (.lnk) target path using Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Modify-shortcut-file-lnk-fdfee592)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out you have to add arguments for something like this

```
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$AppPath = '"app.exe"'
$AppFullPath = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\app\app.exe"'
$cmd = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
$cmdargs = "/c start $AppPath /high $AppFullPath"
$DesktopShortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut('C:\users\user\desktop\app.lnk')
$DesktopShortcut.TargetPath = $cmd
$DesktopShortcut.Arguments = $cmdargs
$DesktopShortcut.Save()
```

Comment: Simple and effective, very useful, thanks a lot!