# how to use " with a variable without it quoting it as a name?

Tags: powershell, variables, shortcut, quotes

I've been trying to write a script that involves creating shortcuts that point to a .ps1 file.
The goal of the script would be to compare two folders and for any files that appear in folder #1 but not folder #2 a shortcut would be created that would have "powershell.exe -file '$shortcutpath'" with $shortcutpath being the location of the file itself and powershell.exe -file being needed to launch the shortcut with Powershell.

This is what I have so far. P.S... There are some lines that are used to remove any unwanted files

> 

```
$sourcelist = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\source" | Get-ItemPropertyvalue -name "name"
$shortcutlist = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\fixes" | Get-ItemPropertyvalue -name "name"


#compare files
$sourceNoShortcutList = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourcelist -DifferenceObject $shortcutlist |Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '=>' |ForEach-Object InputObject
$reqshortcutlist = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourcelist -DifferenceObject $shortcutlist |Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' |ForEach-Object InputObject


#removes unmatched files from fixes folder
foreach($filename in $sourceNoShortcutList){
  $fPath = Join-Path "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\fixes" $fileName 
  Remove-Item -LiteralPath $fPath
}



foreach($filename in $reqshortcutlist){
  $shortcutpath = Join-Path "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\source" $fileName
$pscpath = "powershell.exe -file '$shortcutpath'"
$sclocation = "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\fixes\$filename.lnk"
$WScriptObj = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$shortcut = $WscriptObj.CreateShortcut($sclocation)
$shortcut.TargetPath = $pscpath
$shortcut.Save()
}
```

With

```
$pscpath = "powershell.exe -file '$shortcutpath'"
```

the output looks like this

```
powershell.exe -file 'C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\source\find.ps1'
```

swapping " and ' looks like this

```
powershell.exe -file "$shortcutpath"
```

Looking at scripts I have manually made shortcuts for they look like this

```
powershell.exe -file "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\source\find.ps1"
```

very close to

```
powershell.exe -file 'C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\source\find.ps1'
```

I believe I need to somehow use the " around $shortcutpath but doing so quotes the name instead of the value but this could be wrong

the error I get while running the full script looks like this

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
At C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\Scripts\scmaker\scriptshortcutmaker.ps1:23 char:1
+ $shortcut.TargetPath = $pscpath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

All details listed in post

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Perhaps you just need to double the quotes: `$pscpath = "powershell.exe -file ""$shortcutpath"""`.

Comment: @mikeM Thanks mike, what you suggested worked for what I Thought the issue was.  it looks like the problem is coming form something else tho as I'm still getting the "value does not fall within the expected range." error.

Sorry I wasn't clear in the post but I'm trying to make a shortcut for a powershell script using a powershell script... that requires you to change the start of the target path to powershell.exe -file "filepath" but doing so is throwing up the error above.

Comment: I found this post about a similar problem [Value does not fall within expected range when applying property to Windows 10 Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63287152/value-does-not-fall-within-expected-range-when-applying-property-to-windows-10-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TargetPath` should be a file path without arguments. To pass arguments use the `Arguments` property.

Double quotes can be used inside a double-quoted string if they are escaped using the backtick character or doubled.

```
$shortcut.TargetPath = "powershell.exe"
$shortcut.Arguments = "-File ""$shortcutpath"""
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Mike!
I've been working on this for awhile now and got as far as "powershell.exe -file" "filepath"
the quotes around "powershell.exe -file" were causing issues because of the -file at the end, never thought if putting it before the shortcut path instead!

Thanks for your help I'd have never gotten there without it!